# OneLogin Rate limit cross 5000

Tags: rest, twitter, onelogin

I am currently upgrading from v1-v3 to /1.

we have more than 5000 clients that might login every morning with in a duration of a hour. 
How can I resolve this issue ?

Any suggestions or queries?

### Edit:

John: I will contact the support. I would like to check one the following question:
1. If I change the access token with in an hour if the limit has crossed, will I be able to reset the count back to 5000? Please update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact your customer support representative. We have the ability to up this limit on a per-customer basis.

Comment: John: I will contact the support. I would like to check on one the following question:
1. If I change the access token with in an hour if the limit has crossed, will I be able to reset the count back to 5000? Please update.

Comment: Any comments John.

Comment: The limit is per account, not per key / token / etc. so I'm afraid creating additional tokens won't do anything about the limit.